# two submit dropdown button in one form?

Tags: forms, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Please see this similar question [How to handle two different submit operation from same form in a spring controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658260/how-to-handle-two-different-submit-operation-from-same-form-in-a-spring-controll)

In my case it is **drop down button**.I tried a lot but couldn't find a solution.So how can I handle the different submit operatiins from a single form in the spring controller.

```
<form:form action="someURL">

    <form:select path="cfgObjectType" cssClass="styled-select" 
    onchange="submit()"> 
    <form:option value="Application" >Application</form:option> 
    <form:option value="Agent" >Agent</form:option> 
    <form:option value="all" >all</form:option> 
    </form:select> 


    <form:select path="applnType" cssClass="styled-select" 
    onchange="submit()"> 
    <form:option value="all" >All</form:option> 
    <form:option value="one" >one</form:option> 
    <form:option value="two" >two</form:option> 

    </form:select>

</form:form>
```

Hope our stack users will help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a standard submit button there is a formaction attribute that you can use to specify the alternate action.
http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/submit#HTML_Attributes

There is no attribute for regular form options to support changing the action. Inside the onChange event, instead of supplying submit() as the function, create your own JavaScript function that changes the form action based on the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

First, give your form a name.

```
<form:form action="someURL" name="formname">
```

Then reference the full name in the select onchange method:

```
<form:select path="applnType" cssClass="styled-select" 
onchange="document.formname.submit()">
```